# Ionic LocalNotifications with Capacitor: Cannot find NotificationCompat

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle, android-support-library, localnotification

I'm trying to use IonicNative LocalNotifications (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/) with Capacitor on Ionic 5.
When I try to run the app on android, Android Studio throws an error:

[image: Error-Message: cannot find symbol class NotificationCompat]

The error occurs in module 'capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'. In the corresponding `build.gradle` the support library is implemented:

[image]

How can I make this app compile? I really don't know where to start, so please tell me, if you need any further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetifier fix this, as a solution.

Basically you need to update to AndroidX

```
npm i jetifier
npx jetifier
```

More from Capacitor's [docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/updating#from-1-5-1-to-2-0-0)

Comment: You saved me after 2 days